# GitHub public wikis option: will it give access to write to any gitHub user?

Tags: github

I have a public Github account. In my projects I can see settings (default settings):

**[x] Wikis** 
GitHub Wikis is a simple way to let others contribute content. Any GitHub user can create and edit pages to use for documentation, examples, support, or anything you wish.

**[x] Restrict editing to collaborators only** 
Public wikis will still be readable by everyone.

So question is if I had those options selected (at the same time) does it mean any GitHub user could have had write access to my projects? (As "Public wikis will still be readable by everyone")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The wording and layout in the UI aren't very good, but on [the wiki help page](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/documenting-your-project-with-wikis/changing-access-permissions-for-wikis), it's clear that the second option modifies the first:

- Ticking the first tick-box enables the wiki; unticking [disables the feature completely for that repository](https://help.github.com/articles/disabling-wikis/). I think it's a bug that you can still play with the second tick-box if the wiki is disabled, because it won't make any difference.
- The second tick-box controls who can edit: by default, it's ticked, and only "collaborators" can edit the wiki; untick it [to allow anyone to edit](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-access-permissions-for-wikis/). Either way, anyone can *read* the wiki.

So with both boxes ticked, there will be a wiki, which everyone can read, but only collaborators can edit.

Note that this has no bearing on who can view or edit your actual source code.